# Rails 3 - ERROR Errno::EINVAL: Invalid argument when testing the page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, webrick, internal-server-error

Hio,
i need help. I developed application in Ruby on Rails 3. Its simple application witch some scadfolds and only CRUD operation on mysql database. Because I am Windows 64-bit user i have sometimes problems with some gems(for example mysql2 gem etc.). But until now I have solved every problem. Now i am in situation, when I have application, and already when I test it on localhost I get this error in web browser:

**Internal Server Error
Invalid argument
WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/1.8.7/2011-02-18) at localhost:300**

## Webrick log:

```
*Started GET "/?mobile=0" for 127.0.0.1 at Thu Sep 29 13:25:53 +0200 2011
DEPRECATION WARNING: Setting filter_parameter_logging in ActionController is deprecated and has no longer effect, please set 'config.filter_parameters' in config/application.rb instead. (called from C:/Sites/stodolist/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:8)
  Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"mobile"=>"0"}
  User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  SQL (1.0ms)  BEGIN
  AREL (1.0ms)  UPDATE `users` SET `updated_at` = '2011-09-29 11:25:53', `perishable_token` = '0Mp7RB1VTjml8S7Syqh', `last_request_at` = '2011-09-29 11:25:53' WHERE `users`.`id` = 1
  SQL (22.0ms)  COMMIT
  Task Load (2.0ms)  SELECT `tasks`.* FROM `tasks` WHERE (`tasks`.user_id = 1)
  Priority Load (0.0ms)  SELECT `priorities`.* FROM `priorities` WHERE `priorities`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  Cathegory Load (1.0ms)  SELECT `cathegories`.* FROM `cathegories` WHERE `cathegories`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  Status Load (1.0ms)  SELECT `statuses`.* FROM `statuses` WHERE `statuses`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  Priority Load (1.0ms)  SELECT `priorities`.* FROM `priorities` WHERE `priorities`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1
  Cathegory Load (1.0ms)  SELECT `cathegories`.* FROM `cathegories` WHERE `cathegories`.`id` = 2 *LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `statuses`.* FROM `statuses` WHERE `statuses`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1*
  Priority Load (0.0ms)  SELECT `priorities`.* FROM `priorities` WHERE `priorities`.`id` = 3 LIMIT 1
  Cathegory Load (0.0ms)  SELECT `cathegories`.* FROM `cathegories` WHERE `cathegories`.`id` = 3 LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `statuses`.* FROM `statuses` WHERE `statuses`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  0m  SELECT `priorities`.* FROM `priorities` WHERE `priorities`.`id` = 4 LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `cathegories`.* FROM `cathegories` WHERE `cathegories`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `statuses`.* FROM `statuses` WHERE `statuses`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  Timeline Load (1.0ms)  SELECT `timelines`.* FROM `timelines` WHERE (`timelines`.user_id = 1)
Rendered users/show.html.erb within layouts/application (421.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 619ms (Views: 448.0ms | ActiveRecord: 32.0ms)
[2011-09-29 13:25:57] ERROR Errno::EINVAL: Invalid argument*
    *C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/railsrack/log_tailer.rb:25:in `write'
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:25:in `print'
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:25:in `tail!'
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:15:in `call'
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/content_length.rb:13:in `call'
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:52:in `service'
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:104:in `service'
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:65:in `run'
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:173:in `start_thread'
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start'
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start_thread'
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:95:in `start'
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `each'
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `start'
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:23:in `start'
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:82:in `start'
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:13:in `run'
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:217:in `start'
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:65:in `start'
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:30
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `tap'
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:27
    script/rails:6:in `require'
    script/rails:6*
```

This error shows everytime when I click on some link_to

## Here is my system properties:

1. Windows 7 x86
2. Ruby/1.8.7/2011-02-10
3. WEBrick/1.3.1
4. Rails 3.0.7

## My routes:

```
resources :priorities
resources :timelines
resources :cathegories
resources :statuses
resources :user_sessions
resources :users
resource :user, :as => 'account'
resources :tasks  
match 'signup' => 'users#new', :as => :signup  
match 'admin' => "application#index",      :as => :admin  
match 'login' => "user_sessions#new",      :as => :login
match 'logout' => "user_sessions#destroy", :as => :logout

root :to => "users#show"
```

Really dont no where is the error:( I think it can be in routes...
I'm sry for stupid question, I'm newbie..

Development log:
its weird becouse server log look like this:

```
Started GET "/user" for 127.0.0.1 at Thu Sep 29 14:12:00 +0200 2011
DEPRECATION WARNING: Setting filter_parameter_logging in ActionController is deprecated and has no longer effect, please set 'config.filter_parameters' in config/application.rb instead. (called from C:/Sites/stodolist/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:8)
  Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
  [1m[35mUser Load (1.0ms)[0m  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`persistence_token` = '6e8fba00deefc7922358a3022942302058a31133d7b2dc98bcc1620a06869d36f81c5f42789da7e4fb7b36bddfd4ad628fe547fde111d9fe18af823e0698e8d5' LIMIT 1
  [1m[36mUser Load (2.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 4 LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35mSQL (0.0ms)[0m  BEGIN
  [1m[36mAREL (0.0ms)[0m  [1mUPDATE `users` SET `updated_at` = '2011-09-29 12:12:01', `last_request_at` = '2011-09-29 12:12:01', `perishable_token` = 'v4g9FCSyQfuOAIFXfUQ' WHERE `users`.`id` = 4[0m
  [1m[35mSQL (82.0ms)[0m  COMMIT
  [1m[36mTask Load (1.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT `tasks`.* FROM `tasks` WHERE (`tasks`.user_id = 4)[0m
  [1m[35mTimeline Load (1.0ms)[0m  SELECT `timelines`.* FROM `timelines` WHERE (`timelines`.user_id = 4)
Rendered users/show.html.erb within layouts/application (115.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 321ms (Views: 143.0ms | ActiveRecord: 87.0ms)
```

Comment: Why do your routes have an asterisk (*) at the beginning and at the end? Looks strange and shouldn't be like that.

Comment: sry I added it in this editor. In original they are not there...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found solution of this prob. I decided to change my webserver to morgel. After two hours of working, no error. Maybe this issue really depand on my enviroment- Win 64bit/ruby/mysql/rails3 and webrick. I will see how its going...